# Java Single Link List- Move existing object(node) to the rear end

Tags: java

I am finishing up a small project with Linked list. I have ONE more method to complete, then I will be done. I have completed all of the following methods.

- add front
- add rear
- remove front
- remove rear
- remove atIndex
- remove before node
- remove after node
- moveFront

The last one is `moveRear` method

```
public void moveRear(int index) {
    if (index < 1 || index > size || index == 1 || index == size) {
        System.out.println("Conditions are not met");
        return;
    }
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty");
        return;
    }
    Node cNode = null;
    Node pNode = null;
    cNode = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < index - 1; i++) {
        cNode = cNode.next;
    }
    pNode = head;
    while (pNode.next != null) {
        pNode = pNode.next;
    }
    cNode = cNode.next.next;
    pNode = cNode.next;
    tail = cNode.next;
}
```

I need to link the previous node to the node after the one I am trying to move. So lets say I want to move Node 3 to the rear end. This means that I need Node 2 to link to Node 4 to keep the list connected. Then I need the LAST node to point to Node 3 and then finally have TAIL point to it.

Comment: Do the indexes in your linkedlist start at 0 or at 1? I'm asking because of the first if statement in your method

Comment: Every method in this program the indexes start at 1 not 0. I did index-1 in this case because I wanted to get the reference for the Node BEFORE the one I wanted to move so I can re-connect the Link list. I am not sure why I got a downvote here?

Comment: Link 2 to 4 before moving 3?

Comment: When i move pNode = cNode.next on top I still get the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, with what you have now, you're updating the references but not changing the "next" fields of the nodes. So all you're doing is just resetting what some variables point to. You're not actually changing what cNode's and pNode's next fields, just what the variables, called cNode and pNode, point to. You should instead be updating cNode.next and pNode.next.

Now think about the characteristics of the tail node.

1. The tail's "next" field is always `null`

Also, think about two conditions that are out of the ordinary for this method

1. You want to move the front to the rear (index == 1)
2. You want to move the rear to the rear (cNode.next == tail)

In the first scenario, you not only need to do what you would normally do but you also need to reset the front variable. In the second scenario you don't do anything because the rear is already at the rear. Assuming cNode represents the node before the one you're trying to move to the rear and pNode represents the former rear, this is what everything will look like,

```
public void moveRear(int index) {
    if (index < 1 || index > size || index == size) {//You actually have already 
                                                     //dealt with special case #2
        System.out.println("Conditions are not met");
        return;
    }
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty");
        return;
    }
    Node cNode = null;
    Node pNode = null;
    cNode = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < index-1; i++) {
        cNode = cNode.next;
    }
    pNode = head;
    while (pNode.next !=null){
        pNode = pNode.next;
    }
    if(index==1){ //special case #1
        head = cNode.next; //reset the front to the node after the front node
        pNode.next = cNode; //update the former rear's next field
        tail = pNode.next; //update the tail VARIABLE
    }
    else{ //what you would do if it was not either special case
        pNode.next = cNode.next;//reset the former rear's next field first
        cNode.next = cNode.next.next;//then change cNode's next field, ORDER MATTERS HERE
        tail = pNode.next;//then reset the rear VARIABLE

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in the last 3 lines. `cNode` points to the node previous to one that you want move (let's call it `target`) and it's ok, but you override it with `cNode = cNode.next.next;` so you can't now change `next` value (which should point to the node after the `target`). Also because you move `target` to the end of the list you don't have to search for `pNode`, you already have `tail`.

```
public void moveRear(int index) {
    if (index < 1 || index > size || index == 1 || index == size) {
        System.out.println("Conditions are not met");
        return;
    }
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty");
        return;
    }

    // search node previous to target
    Node cNode = null;
    cNode = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < index-1; i++) {
        cNode = cNode.next;
    }

    // remember target
    Node target = cNode.next;

    // exclude target from list
    cNode.next = cNode.next.next;

    // add target to the tail
    tail.next = target;
    target.next = null;
    tail = target;
}
```

Also if you want to handle situation when `index == 1` you can simply add the following

```
if(index == 1) {
    Node tmp = head.next;
    tail.next = head;
    head.next = null;
    head = tmp;
    return;
}
```

before the search part (`Node cNode = null;`).

```
public void moveRear(int index) {
    if (index < 1 || index > size || index == size) {
        System.out.println("Conditions are not met");
        return;
    }
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty");
        return;
    }

    if(index == 1) {
        Node tmp = head.next;
        tail.next = head;
        head.next = null;
        head = tmp;
        return;
    }

    // search node previous to target
    Node cNode = null;
    cNode = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < index-1; i++) {
        cNode = cNode.next;
    }

    // remember target
    Node target = cNode.next;

    // exclude target from list
    cNode.next = cNode.next.next;

    // add target to the tail
    tail.next = target;
    target.next = null;
    tail = target;
}
```

Comment: I just finished the index 1 scenario myself. I did it kind of differently for index 1, but it is still the same amount of line of code. I am not sure why this last method caused me so many problems. TY !

Comment: @SkyZ If the one of the answers was helpful and solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I could not get my head around the pNode and cNode reference variables.

Below is a code which does what's needed. I assumed the fact that we are maintaining a `tail` reference node which always points to the last node in the list.

```
public void moveRear(int index) {

    if (index < 1 || index > size || index == 1 || index == size) {
        System.out.println("Conditions are not met");
        return;
    }
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty");
        return;
    }

    Node previousToTheOneWhichNeedsToBeMoved = null;
    previousToTheOneWhichNeedsToBeMoved = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < index - 1; i++) {
        previousToTheOneWhichNeedsToBeMoved = previousToTheOneWhichNeedsToBeMoved.next;
    }

    Node needsToBeMoved = previousToTheOneWhichNeedsToBeMoved.next;

    previousToTheOneWhichNeedsToBeMoved.next = needsToBeMoved.next;
    tail.next = needsToBeMoved;
    needsToBeMoved.next = null;
}
```

Also, below is the Unit Test which passes. The LinkedList constructor used below looks like this:

`LinkedList(Node head, Node tail, int size)`

```
@Test
public void should_TraverseList_Given_3elements(){
    Node one = new Node(1);
    Node two = new Node(2);
    Node three = new Node(3);
    one.next = two;
    two.next = three;
    three.next = null;

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList(one, three, 3);

    assertEquals("123", list.toString());

    list.moveRear(2);
    assertEquals("132", list.toString());
}

@Test
public void should_TraverseList_Given_4elements(){
    Node one = new Node(1);
    Node two = new Node(2);
    Node three = new Node(3);
    Node four = new Node(4);
    one.next = two;
    two.next = three;
    three.next = four;
    four.next = null;

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList(one, four, 4);

    assertEquals("1234", list.toString());

    list.moveRear(2);
    assertEquals("1342", list.toString());
}
```

P.S. Index starts at 1